# Optimise Command on Delta Table

Tags: optimization, databricks, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

I have delta table with liquid clustering enabled, Can I run Optimise command on the Delta Table when an another write Operation is going on the table, Will it corrupt the Data, How the Logs and metadata will be updated in this case?

I am confused about this if we can optimise the table or not.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have not disabled deletion vectors, you have row-level concurrency which makes it so that OPTIMIZE does not conflict with any write operations - see [this table](https://docs.databricks.com/en/optimizations/isolation-level.html#write-conflicts-with-row-level-concurrency).